# Inserting data into a file on Windows

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c, windows

First a little background:

I'm creating a Windows application that will deal with huge files. I want to insert data (or remove it) into the file at a given offset without having to rewrite the data that follows, I'd want the system to 'expand' or 'shrink' the file for me. I know it's possible on Linux with sed, even that wouldn't help me though since I will be dealing mostly with binary data.

Now, is it possible to achieve that either in .NET or native C/C++? Any tips will be helpful.

Comment: There are no commonly-available file systems that allow this.

Comment: @MartinJames All major filesystems support messing around with allocation unit pointers to allow sparse files and easy inserts, but the simplest solution is just to copy data, I assume the OP knows this.

Comment: The System.IO.FileStream supports seek, so that should allow you to write to the file at different locations within it, but a direct insert is, to my knowledge, not possible.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I know the simplest solution is copying, it's a no-go though. I need to either make it work like in the question or I'll have to make the design a lot uglier. Please elaborate on messing with allocation unit pointers please.

Comment: I suspect you will need ugliness.  Can you not use a 'real' DB for this requirement?

Comment: @MartinJames Would be funny writing a DB-like project and using an external database, really...

Comment: DB are internally ugly.  There is a reason for that:)

Comment: If the file system was forced to handle random inserts/deletes, the disk would fill up with linked-lists and trees of sparse, partial clusters.

Comment: Which is pretty close to what happens on NTFS anyway. Well, I'll redesign the whole thing I guess. Thanks for your input nevertheless :)

Comment: This is more of an OS / file system than a programming language question.  Like @Dai mentioned, some filesytems support "sparse" files. With a 4KB allocation unit, writes of 10 bytes to offset 1 and 1000000 will only allocate 2 blocks of disk space (instead of 250 blocks).  There must be a reason DB systems do not use sparse files.

Comment: I assume you have looked at B-tree's.

Comment: sed on LInux we rewrite the entire file, not update it in place.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not aware of a file system that provides such a service, there is an alternative. If you can afford the added complexity, you can  have a somewhat complex format of your file:

1. The regular contents which changes rarely (at daily backup/checkpoint/snapshot or something like that), followed by
2. Log of changes to the contents

Thus, on "backup/checkpoint" you "execute the log" and leave it empty. Think of it as a journalling file, instead of a journalling filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it won't really help me though I'm afraid. I can afford lots of added complexity, I can't afford heavy tasks like this one. An incremental log of changes is not a terrible idea, it's just way too slow for me :)